# Remove lines from files

Tags: python

I have a lot of files which have comments beginning with ! and I need to remove all of those, then replace the #Mhz with # Mhz on the next line and keep the file name same. What is an efficient way of doing this? I can read the file and write to a new file in a different directory and manually delete them later i guess but is there a better way?

Comment: The **'#Mhz'** strings must be replaced with **'# Mhz'** only if they are at the beginning of a line ?? And only if they are on the line that follows a line beginning with **'!'** ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a stupidly simple way:

```
for line in in_file:
    if line[0] == '!':
        continue
    if line.startswith('#Mhz'):
        line = '# MHz' + line[4:] # Assuming it's megahertz, it's spelled MHz.
    out_file.write(line)
```

You can read the whole input file and split it into lines then open the file for writing if you want to do it in place.

Comment: thanks a lot, so if i open the file in rw mode would i be able to replace the lines as i go?

Comment: @Illusionist: No, you have to open it in read mode, suck out the text (with `file.readlines()`), then close it and reopen it in write mode. You could write to a file-like object then copy it into the original file, but that's a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

The `fileimput` module is a good choice when you want to filter one (or more) files in-place:

```
import fileinput
import sys

files_ = fileinput.input(['somefile.ext','anotherfile'], inplace=1)
for line in files_:
    if line.startswith('#Mhz'):
        sys.stdout.write('# Mhz' + line[4:])
    elif line[0] != '!':
        sys.stdout.write(line)
files_.close()  # cancel stdin & stdout redirection
```

The first argument to `fileinput.input()` can also be a single filename instead of a sequence of them or, if left out, they're automatically taken from successive `sys.argv[1:]` arguments, or `sys.stdin` if there aren't any -- allowing it to easily handle multiple file seamlessly as written. It can also automatically make backup files and has numerous other useful features, all of which are described in detail in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput).

In Python 3.2+ it also can be used in conjunction with a Python **with** statement which would allow the code above to simplified slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say anything in the question about why/if it needed to be in python.

If you're only doing this to one or a few files, one very simple way to do this would be to open a file in vim and type

```
:%s/^!.*\n#Mhz/# Mhz/
```

and possibly

```
:%s/^!.*\n//
```

to get lines to remove that aren't followed by `#Mhz`, then save the file and quit with

```
:wq
```

Comment: it can be in other languages too, i just know a bit of python... but there are a lot of files

Comment: This would probably be best represented as a sed script, unless anyone not intimately familiar with sed will ever need to modify it.

Comment: If you mean my example should have used sed, not vim, then probably, but I demonstrated in vim because (a) the gist is the same, (b) I'm less familiar with multiline matches in sed, and (c) you can check what you're doing and possibly tweak it before saving the changes.

Comment: I meant that the solution to the problem should probably use sed. The approach using an editor has the disadvantage that it doesn't scale to multiple files well.

Answer (score 0):

With mode `'r+'` , no need of `open in 'r' - read - shut - reopen in 'w' - write -shut` , all can be done in the same opening of the same file

From this sentence :

> then replace the #Mhz with # Mhz on
>   the **next** line

I understood that **'#Mhz'** must be replaced with **'# Mhz'** only if **'#Mhz'** is present in a line that follows a line beginning with **'!'**

If so, the following code does the job for files that are not too big (so that they can easily be loaded in the RAM)

```
import re
regx = re.compile('^!.*\r?\n((?!!)(.*?)(#Mhz)(.*\r?\n))?',re.MULTILINE)

def repl(mat):
    return (mat.group(2)+'# Mhz'+mat.group(4) if mat.group(2)
            else mat.group(1))

with open(filename,'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write(regx.sub(repl,content))
    f.truncate()
```

For enomrous files, another algorithm must be employed.